# cannot parse datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Column Name: dateAdded

format: 2017-03-03T16:56:05Z

I am trying this code

```
df = pd.read_csv ('amazon.csv')
df['dateAdded'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateAdded'], format= '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S%Z')
```

Error:

> **time data '2017-03-03T16:56:05Z' does not match format '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S%Z' (match)**

Comment: You just have one too many `%`. No `%` in front of the Z -> `'%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%SZ'` (Tested with this sample `df = pd.DataFrame({'dateAdded': ['2017-03-03T16:56:05Z']})`)

Answer (score 0):

`Z`, or `Military Time` is not supported in `Datetime`. The solution is to either remove the `Z` or replace it with `+00:00`. Your code becomes:

```
df['dateAdded'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateAdded'].rsplit('Z', 1)[0], format= '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S')
```

Or if you are using a newer version that supports the Military Time then your solution is to simply replace the `%Z` in your `format` with `%z` (small letter).

```
df['dateAdded'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateAdded'].rsplit('Z', 1)[0], format= '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

Another (better IMO) approach is to convert the datetime without using `pandas`.

```
from datetime import datetime
df['dateAdded'] = datetime.fromisoformat(df['dateAdded'])
```

though you're going to have to edit the code above to go over the entire column.

Comment: I have tried that I am still getting error "Series' object has no attribute 'rsplit"

Comment: then make it `str(df['dateAdded']).rsplit` @suhaspaunikar

Comment: thanks i wrore         df['dateAdded'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateAdded'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['dateAdded'] = pd.to_datetime(str(df['dateAdded']).rsplit('Z', 1)[0], format= '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S')     and i am getting error ValueError: time data '0       2017-03-03 16:56:05
1       2017-03-03 16:56:05
2       2017-03-03 16:56:05
3       2017-03-03 16:56:05
4       2017-03-03 16:56:05

33330   2017-03-06 14:59:43
33331   2017-03-06 14:59:43
Name: dateAdded, Length: 33332, dtype: datetime64[ns]' does not match format '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: i am getting error